# How do I form Pivot table for two categorical variables?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

My data looks smth like:

| Index | Job | Y | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Yes | 1 |
| 2 | B | No | 2 |
| 3 | A | No | 5 |
| 4 | A | No | 0 |
| 5 | B | Yes | 4 |

I want to summarize the data in the following format, with job in the row and Y in the column:

|  | Yes | No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 1 |

I have tried the following code:

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(index =['job'], columns = ['y'], values = ['balance'], aggfunc ='count')
```

I am not able to run the pivot without using balance in the value parameter. How do I get the above result?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
res = pd.crosstab(df.Job, df.Y)

res

Y    No  Yes
Job         
A     2    1
B     1    1

# to get rid of the names for the columns (`Y`) and index (`Job`):
res.columns.name = None
res.index.name = None

res

   No  Yes
A   2    1
B   1    1
```